# Remove up button from action bar when navigating using BottomNavigationView with Android Navigation UI library

Tags: android-support-library, android-navigation, android-jetpack

I've created a small app that has three fragments for top-level navigation through a BottomNavigationView. If you launch the app and click on a navigation button on the bottom nav, you are presented with an up button in the action bar. Here is the code for the activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
        setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
        setupWithNavController(bottomNav, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean
            = findNavController(navHostFragment).navigateUp()

}
```

Here is a screenshot of the result. The app is launched on the home screen and all I've done is simply click the profile button from the BottomNavigationView.

[image]

I've tried listening to the BottomNavigationView's item selections and navigating manually using different [NavOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptions) to no avail. Is there anything we can do to avoid showing an up button in the action bar while the user is navigating with a BottomNavigationView?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Starting with 1.0.0-alpha07 you can use `AppBarConfiguration` to configure that behaviour.

`AppBarConfiguration` has a Builder constructor so you can create a new `Builder` with a specific set of top level destinations, referenced by their `id` (this `id` is the one you set on your navigation layout).

Create new `AppBarConfiguration`:

```kotlin
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration
            .Builder(
                    R.id.navigationHomeFragment,
                    R.id.navigationListFragment,
                    R.id.navigationProfileFragment)
            .build()
```

Then, instead of `setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)` you need to call `setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)`

This is the right way to handle top navigation behaviours.

Comment: Uh, okay this component is like magic now I don't know wtf is going on :)

Comment: Great solution (Y)

Comment: Saved the day :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks. But starting with 1.0.0 I had to call setupWithNavController( navController, appBarConfiguration) to make it work

Comment: thank you , great solution to hide Up Navigation for some fragments

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and I found a way to get the current fragment with the **NavController.addOnNavigatedListener**, so I applied the following logic within my Activity and for now it works for me

```java
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    val navHost = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragment) as NavHostFragment

    navHost.navController.addOnNavigatedListener { _, destination ->
        val showButton = showUpButton(destination.id)
        //Here occurs the magic
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(showButton)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(showButton)
    }
}

//Check according to your convenience which fragment id
//should show or hide the "Up Button"
private fun showUpButton(id: Int): Boolean {
    return id != R.id.your_home_fragment && id != R.id.your_list_fragment 
            && id != R.id.your_profile_fragment
}
```

And this is my project...

[image]

I do not know if it is the best option but if someone has any better suggestion, it will be welcome

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead of `setupWithNavController`:

```java
navController.addOnNavigatedListener(new NavController.OnNavigatedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onNavigated(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination) {
         toolbar.setTitle(destination.getLabel());
     }
});
```

Or the equivalent in Kotlin.

The only thing `setupWithNavController` does is add a listener to change the toolbar title, and creates the up button. If you don't want the up button, just add a listener which changes the toolbar title only.

Comment: Thanks Bob, this solved my problem.  People like you are why I love Stackoverflow.

Comment: keep in mind that the `addOnNavigatedListener` has been changed to `addOnDestinationChangedListener` in new version of navigation component

Answer (score 2):

You could set the navigation icon to null, or change the icon only for some destinations
eg:

1) ***In Kotlin:***

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            toolbar.title = destination.label
            toolbar.navigationIcon = null
}
```

2) ***In Java:***

```
hostFragment.getNavController().addOnDestinationChangedListener(new OnDestinationChangedListener() {
    public final void onDestinationChanged(@NotNull NavController controller, @NotNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        toolbar.setTitle(destination.getLabel());
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController` [check out `onNavDestinationSelected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/ui/package-summary#onnavdestinationselected).

Inside your bottom navigation view `menu.xml`, add `android:menuCategory="secondary"` to the corresponding `MenuItem`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/bottom_nav_icon_profile"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    android:title="@string/profile" />
```

Comment: Applying the `android:menuCategory="secondary"` attribute to the items in the bottom navigation *menu.xml* does **not hide** the up-button in my case. I was able to hide it by applying the `AppBarConfiguration` as [suggested by Javier Cancio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463839/356895). - Setting `secondary` however has the effect that when BACK is pressed the navigation returns to the **previous** bottom navigation element (having 3 or more). Without `secondary` always the **primary** element will be navigated to. Is there anything I am missing with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In Java this works for me:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration
            .Builder(navController.getGraph())
            .build();
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);

    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
        toolbar.setTitle(destination.getLabel());
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
    });
```