# How to disable UP in Navigation for some fragment with the new Navigation Architecture Component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I am trying out the new [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/), and I can't figure out how to do this:

I have 1 Activity (MainActivity) + 3 Fragments:

- SplashFragment (Home)
- MainFragment
- SignUpFragment

I would like to use SplashFragment to determine if I should navigate to MainFragment or SignUpFragment, but once it reaches either of those 2, you should not be able to pop back to SplashFragment. How can I do that with the new navigation component?

I tried `popBackStack` before and after calling `navigate(R.id.action_xxx)`, but neither of them work (which make sense: before it has nothing to pop; after it just closes the fragment that just got added). Does that mean the only way to do that is to override `onBackPress` to intercept it and make sure `navigateUp` does not get call in those cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, add attributes `app:popUpTo='your_nav_graph_id'` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` to the action tag.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/signInFragment"
    android:name="com.glee.incog2.android.fragment.SignInFragment"
    android:label="fragment_sign_in"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sign_in" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_signInFragment_to_usersFragment"
        app:destination="@id/usersFragment"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/main_nav_graph"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</fragment>
```

Second, navigate to the destination, using the above action as parameter.

```
findNavController(fragment).navigate(SignInFragmentDirections.actionSignInFragmentToUserNameFragment())
```

**NOTE**: If you navigate using method `navigate(@IdRes int resId)`, you won't get the desired result. Hence, I used method `navigate(@NonNull NavDirections directions)`.

Comment: The popUpTo value need to be not nav_graph_id, but the id of the root of the graph, thus using navigate(@IdRes int resId) worked just fine for me.

Comment: Can you be more specific to that?

Comment: To clarify for those who were confused like me - `popUpTo` means "remove everything before this fragment" if `popUpToInclusive` is set to true it means "Remove this fragment AND everything before it" Also make sure you use the id of the **action** when navigating, not the id of the fragment you're navigating to.

Comment: Note: you need to add the Navigation Component Safe Args plugin to your project for that *Directions class in step 2 to be generated.

Comment: It's working with back button but the navigation up button is visible in MainFragment and clicks on up, navigate to splashFragment. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @shantanu you can configure a set of top level destinations (i.e. these fragments won't display the up button). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463839/8781554

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me in alpha05 release. Add app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph" in the action tag(inside your nav_graph.xml file).
Here "@id/nav_graph is the id of my graph or also called as the Root.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/startFragment">
.......
<action
android:id="@+id/action_startFragment_to_homeFragment"
app:destination="@id/homeFragment" 
app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"/>
.......
```

You can also do this in design tab:- select "SplashFragment" and select the action you want to change and then pick "root" for "Pop To"

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please re-format your answer so that it would easy to understand?

Comment: I think it's better to set popUpTo value to the id of the root of the graph, I mean your startDestination id value as the clearTask attribute deprecation message says. You should also set popUpToInclusive to true.

Answer (score 7):

**WARNING: `clearTask` has been deprecated and will be remove in future release, not sure what the solution is. Please follow [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80338878) for now to keep up to date**

---

Oh after 10 minutes finally found the key: use `clearTask`.

All I have to do is add `app:clearTask="true"` to that specific action, or use `.navigate(R.id.actionXXXX, null, NavOptions.Builder().setClearTask(true).build())`, and it's done. Just make sure you add it to all the children of SplashFragment (in this case, both MainFragment and SignUpFragment).

Comment: But it say setClearTask has been deprecated. Shouldn't we look for alternatives.

Comment: @MuM6oJuM6o good find! I just commented on the issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80338878), hopefully will got a reply soon. Will also add a warning to the answer.

Comment: I did some looking up in the docs, turns out Google has another method to achieve this. Its called NavOptions.setPopUpTo(destinationId:Int , inclusive:boolean). Unfortunately, i was unable to achieve the desired outcome.
[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptions.Builder.html#setPopUpTo(int,%20boolean))

Comment: @MuM6oJuM6o I had the same problem, but after looking again at the deprecation message of clearTask xml attribute attentively, which says "set popUpTo to the root of your graph and use popUpToInclusive", I have done as it says and achieved the desired behavior. With this, you can still use findNavController().navigate(@IdRes resId, bundle)

Answer (score 3):

So if you have splash fragment and main fragment and you don't want to go back to splash fragment after the main fragment below method you can achieve this

```
<fragment
     android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
     android:name="com.example.youappname.views.SplashFragment"
     android:label="fragment_splash"
     tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
     <action
         android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_mainFragment"
         app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
         app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment"
         app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</fragment>
```

In you Kotlin Splash Fragment:

```
private lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

      navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)

}

private fun navigateToMainFrag() {
      navController.navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_mainFragment)
}
```

Now when you press back button it will close the app instead of showing the splash screen

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wanted to do this purely in code:

```
Navigation.findNavController(v)
.navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_userProfileFragment2, null, 
new NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.splashFragment, true).build())
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample solution is add a `onBackPressedDispatcher` on `Owner Activity` of fragment/navigation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#implement_custom_back_navigation