# How to clear navigation Stack after navigating to another fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I am using The new **[Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing)** in android and I am stuck in clearing the navigation stack after moving to a new fragment.

Example: 
I am in the loginFragment and I want this fragment to be cleared from the stack when I navigate to the home fragment so that the user will not be returned back to the loginFragment when he presses the back button.

I am using a simple [NavHostFragment.findNavController(Fragment).navigate(R.id.homeFragment)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment#findNavController(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) to navigate.

Current Code :

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        NavHostFragment.findNavController(LoginFragment.this).navigate(R.id.homeFragment);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

I tried using the [NavOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptions.Builder) in the [navigate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate_7), but the back button is still sending me back to the loginFragment

```
NavOptions.Builder navBuilder = new NavOptions.Builder();
NavOptions navOptions = navBuilder.setPopUpTo(R.id.homeFragment, false).build();   
             NavHostFragment.findNavController(LoginFragment.this).navigate(R.id.homeFragment, null, navOptions);
```

Comment: You can use `popBackStack` or don't add `LoginFragment` to backstack provide `null` to `addToBackStack(null);` and replace it with new `Fragment`

Comment: I think @Yupi  has provided a good suggestion.  Or you could use the `navigate()` method  like `navigate(int resId, Bundle args, NavOptions navOptions)` and provide the `NavOptions` that best fit your senario

Comment: I tried using The NavOptions but the back button is still sending me back to the loginFragment

Comment: In navigation graph you can add app:popUpTo="@+id/desiredFragment" for homeFragment action, when user will click back he will be navigated to desiredFragment and not loginFragment

Comment: @Alex I tried doing that but it's not having any effects.

Comment: you could you use alternative approach without clearing back stack described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997438/3278271

Answer (score 416, accepted):

First, add attributes `app:popUpTo='your_nav_graph_id'` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` to the action tag.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/signInFragment"
    android:name="com.glee.incog2.android.fragment.SignInFragment"
    android:label="fragment_sign_in"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sign_in" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_signInFragment_to_usersFragment"
        app:destination="@id/usersFragment"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/main_nav_graph"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</fragment>
```

Second, navigate to the destination, using above action as parameter.

```
findNavController(fragment).navigate(
     SignInFragmentDirections.actionSignInFragmentToUserNameFragment())
```

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop) for more information.

**NOTE**: If you navigate using method `navigate(@IdRes int resId)`, you won't get the desired result. Hence, I used method `navigate(@NonNull NavDirections directions)`.

Comment: Best answer as clearTask is now deprecated in new versions of Android Navigation Component!

Comment: One can also use the id of the action like so `findNavController(fragment).navigate(R.id.action_signInFragment_to_usersFragment)`

Comment: Awesome! However, now I have the back/up glyph, but pressing it doesn't do anything. What's a clean way to remove that too?

Comment: I can not understand this `app:popUpTo="@+id/main_nav_graph" app:popUpToInclusive="true"` but it is working - previous fragment destroyes. Without this 2 lines only going to hidden state..

Comment: when using this way, it actually destroy the old one and create a new one, what if i want to get back to the old one?

Comment: I think the key to this answer lies in that the "popUpTo" (which removes all fragments between your current fragment and the first occurrence of the id that you pass to this argument) is set to the *id of the navigation graph itself*. Effectively completely clearing the backstack. Only adding this comment because I haven't seen it explained exactly like this, and it was what I was looking for. +1!

Comment: A bit late to the party but I tried this solution and faced some other problem. The up button still appears and takes me up to the 1st fragment.
Check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625934/android-unable-to-clear-the-back-stack-of-all-fragments-with-navigation-compone

Comment: **NOTE**: Not that "Directions" class will not be generated if you didn't included safe-args gradle. For more info visit [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/android-navigation-components-part-3-19554ec9ae83.)

Comment: Only work in one of my fragment, not all.Not sure why

Comment: I am sorry, but what is "your_nav_graph_id"?

Comment: @JaydipKalkani 's link 404d and is no longer available. Here are the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#safeargs)

Comment: Anybody investigated why " If you navigate using method navigate(@IdRes int resId), you won't get the desired result." ?

Comment: How to clear backstack if I navigate from fragment to activity using navigation architecture component?

Comment: @ScottO'Toole your comment is literally the best answer to any popUp related questions. Game changer!

Comment: if you dont use safe-args and you want the desired result try:
val navController = findNavController()
        navController.popBackStack()
        navController.navigate(navController.graph.startDestinationId)

Comment: Wow. If you're like me, you were trying this with a fragment that navigates to an activity and it would. Not. Work. Here is a solution, but be warned, it's ugly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68355036/navigation-component-how-to-clear-back-stack-when-navigating-from-fragment-to-a. I might just refactor my two nav graphs into one so I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 104):

I think your question specifically pertains on how to use the Pop Behavior / Pop To / app:popUpTo (in xml)

In documentation,
*Pop up to a given destination before navigating. This pops all non-matching destinations from the back stack until this destination is found.*

Example (Simple Job hunting app)
my **start_screen_nav** graph is like this:

```
startScreenFragment (start) -> loginFragment -> EmployerMainFragment

                            -> loginFragment -> JobSeekerMainFragment
```

if I want to navigate to `EmployerMainFragment` and pop all **including** `startScreenFragment` then the  code will be:

```
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_employerMainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/employerMainFragment"

            app:popUpTo="@+id/startScreenFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

if I want to navigate to `EmployerMainFragment` and pop all **excluding** `startScreenFragment` then the  code will be:

```
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_employerMainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/employerMainFragment"

            app:popUpTo="@+id/startScreenFragment"/>
```

if I want to navigate to `EmployerMainFragment` and pop `loginFragment` but **not** `startScreenFragment` then the  code will be:

```
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_employerMainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/employerMainFragment"

            app:popUpTo="@+id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

**OR**

```
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_employerMainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/employerMainFragment"

            app:popUpTo="@+id/startScreenFragment"/>
```

Comment: How to do this programmatically instead of in XML?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky KotlinDSL

Answer (score 76):

In my case i needed to remove everything in the back Stack before i open a new fragment so i used this code

```
navController.popBackStack(R.id.fragment_apps, true);
navController.navigate(R.id.fragment_company);
```

the first line removes the back Stack till it reaches the fragment specified in my case it's the home fragment so it's removes all the back stack completely , and when the user clicks back in the fragment_company he closes the app.

Comment: What is `fragment_apps`??

Comment: The current fragment. It's like if u are on fragmentOne and want to go fragmentTwo u need too use navController.popBackStack(R.id.fragmentOne, true);
navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentTwo);

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me (Navigation v2.3.5).

Answer (score 27):

Going to add another answer here as none of the above worked for me ... we have multiple nav graphs.

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.dashboard_graph,null,NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(findNavController().graph.startDestination, true).build())
```

This was the only way that I could successfully clear the full back stack. Google really need to make this simpler.

Comment: This was very useful. I had already defined popUpTo and popUpToInclusive in XML AND preforming the navigation using the NavDirections not the ID but still at times it failed. Using the back/up navigation retuned the user to the original starting destination :(

Comment: In a multi-module environment, this seems to be the only working answer besides some really other horrifying hacks.

Answer (score 16):

**NOTE:** Clear task is deprecated, official description is

> This method is deprecated. Use setPopUpTo(int, boolean) with the id of the NavController's graph and set inclusive to true.

**Old Answer**

If you don't wanna go through all that fuzz in code, you can simply check `Clear Task` in `Launch Options` in properties of the action.

[image: Launch Options]

**Edit:** As of Android Studio 3.2 Beta 5, Clear Task is no longer visible in Launch Options window, but you can still use it in navigation's XML code, in **action** tag, by adding

```
app:clearTask="true"
```

Comment: You should use the id of the root of the graph instead as the clearTask xml attributedeprecation message says: "set popUpTo to the root of your graph and use popUpToInclusive". I have done it like this and achieved the same desired behavior with findNavController().navigate(@IdRes resId, bundle)

Comment: Using the recommended approach of setting popUpTo and popUpToInclusive doesn't seem to be working for actions between destinations other that the start destination: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116831650

Comment: I'm actually encountering an issue where it doesn't work with start destination, frustrating.

Comment: How would you do this if you don't know the fragment to which you wish to pop? For example I have a fragment that creates a new item. After creating I want to show the details view of this item. But I don't want the user to pop back to the create fragment afterwards but to the previous view. That can either be a list of all items or a different item on which the new one was based. Is then clearTask the only option?

Comment: No, it actually shouldn't be used anymore. Instead you should use popUpTo inclusively. I will update the answer very soon with my findings of popUpTo usage.

Answer (score 13):

```
    NavController navController 
    =Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(),          
    R.id.nav_host_fragment);// initialize navcontroller

    if (navController.getCurrentDestination().getId() == 
     R.id.my_current_frag) //for avoid crash
  {
    NavDirections action = 
    DailyInfoSelectorFragmentDirections.actionGoToDestionationFragment();

    //for clear current fragment from stack
    NavOptions options = new 
    NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.my_current_frag, true).build();
    navController.navigate(action, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

I finally figure it out thanks to [How to disable UP in Navigation for some fragment with the new Navigation Architecture Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336112/how-to-disable-up-in-navigation-for-some-fragment-with-the-new-navigation-archit)

I had to specify .setClearTask(true) as a NavOption.

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");


                        NavOptions.Builder navBuilder = new NavOptions.Builder();
                        NavOptions navOptions = navBuilder.setClearTask(true).build();
                        NavHostFragment.findNavController(LoginFragment.this).navigate(R.id.homeFragment,null,navOptions);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());

                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: Glad to see you were able to implement my suggestion of using `navigate(int resId, Bundle args, NavOptions navOptions)` and `NavOptions`

Comment: bad to bad style idea

Comment: yeah "setClearTask" is deprecated but instead you can use: 

`val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.my_current_frag, true).build()`

`findNavController().navigate(R.id.my_next_frag, null, navOptions)`

Comment: @PabloReyes It works. However, it just remove the last one. Is there any way to clear all the fragments in the stack and start over?

Comment: @c-an it should work. Probably you're using a wrong destination fragmentId (e.g. `R.id.my_next_frag` could be like login or splash screen); also if you want to popBack just one, you can use: `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).popBackStack()`.

Comment: @PabloReyes This is the correct answer.
Just specify which fragment is the last to remove:
Say you have this stack:
Fragment_1 
Fragment_2
Fragment_3

You are now on Fragment_3 and want to navigate to Fragment_4 and clear all other fragments.
Just specify in the navigation xml:
  app:popUpTo="@id/Fragment_1"
  app:popUpToInclusive="true"

Comment: Why not just call `popBackStack`?

Answer (score 10):

*use this code*

```
navController.navigateUp();
```

then call new Fragment
android version 4.1.2

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I am getting it done.

```
 //here the R.id refer to the fragment one wants to pop back once pressed back from the newly  navigated fragment
 val navOption = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.startScorecardFragment, false).build()

//now how to navigate to new fragment
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)
                    .navigate(R.id.instoredBestPractice, null, navOption)
```

Comment: Why is your **inclusive** flag `false`?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptions.Builder#setPopUpTo(int,%20boolean))

`inclusive boolean: true to also pop the given destination from the back stack`

So, I set the inclusive to false because I don't want to pop the current fragment from the stack.

Answer (score 7):

For

```
// Navigation library
    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

This solution work for me

```
 
findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.<Current Fragment Id In NavGraph>, true)

 
findNavController().navigate(R.id.< Your Destination Fragment  in NavGraph>)
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case where I used **Navigation component** with **NavigationView** (menu drawer):

1.

```
mNavController.popBackStack(R.id.ID_OF_FRAGMENT_ROOT_TO_POP, true)
```

2. 

```
    mNavController.navigate(
      R.id.DESTINATION_ID,
      null,
      NavOptions.Builder()
                .setPopUpTo(R.id.POP_TO_DESTINATION_ID, true)
                .build()
    )
```

*I wanted to clear the stack after clicking on logout on side menu drawer!
Hope that helped someone!*

Comment: Could you explain a bit what you have done here? Do I have to copy/paste those 2 options or is it either one or the other?

Comment: godlike answer @Yasser AKBBACH

Answer (score 4):

You can override the back pressed of the base activity like this :

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

  val navigationController = nav_host_fragment.findNavController()
  if (navigationController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.firstFragment) {
    finish()
  } else if (navigationController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.secondFragment) {
    // do nothing
  } else {
    super.onBackPressed()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Non of the solutions above works for me.
After spending hours on it, here is my solution:

Note: I have multiple `nav_graphs` and switching between fragments in different `nav_graphs`.

1. **Define your action as below in xml**:

> ```
> <action
>     android:id="@id/your_action_id"
>     app:destination="@id/the_fragment_id_you_want_to_navigate_to"
>     app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph_which_contains_destination_fragment"
>     app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
> ```

2. **Navigate using action above from your Java/Kotlin code:**

> ```
> findNavController(R.id.your_nav_name)?.apply {
>     navigate(R.id.your_action_id)
>     backQueue.clear()
> }
> ```

Comment: backQueue is private now unfortunately. Any new way to archive this?

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing it **programmatically** you can continue with the following way:

```
           findNavController().navigate(

                //your navigation direction
                R.id.action_fragmentB_to_fragmentC,

                //pass arguments if you have, else null
                null,

                //Pass the fragment id where you want to land on the back press at fragmentC,
                //true/false, in case you want to remove the fragmentA from the back stack use the TRUE and vice versa 
                NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.fragmentA, true).build() 
            )
```

Also, you can achieve that in the following way in the **navigation graph** XML as below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Jetpack Compose ❤️

```
navHostController.navigate(Routes.HOME) {
                            this.popUpTo(Routes.ONBOARDING) {
                                this.inclusive = true
                            }
                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a while to prevent the back button from going back to my start fragment, which in my case was an intro message that should only appear once.

The easy solution was to create a [global action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) pointing to the destination that the user should stay on. You have to set `app:popUpTo="..."` correctly - set it to the destination you want to get popped off. In my case it was my intro message. Also set `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`

Answer (score 0):

For `androidx.compose` version **1.2.0+**

I had a few issues with lower versions but 1.2 plus (beta at the time of writing this), works perfectly.

Better syntax for the navGraph in Compose:

```
navController.navigate(item.name) {

    navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { route ->
        // use saveState = false to NOT save the state for the popped route
        popUpTo(route) { saveState = true }
    }

    launchSingleTop = true

    restoreState = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using button to navigate to other fragments so on each button click I am doing this.

```
 val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setLaunchSingleTop(true).setPopUpTo(R.id.homeFragment, false).build()
 findNavController(R.id.mainNavHostFragment).navigate(R.id.destination, null, navOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best practice but it works for me (Kotlin/Fragment)

```
while (findNavController().navigateUp()){findNavController().popBackStack()}
findNavController().navigate(R.id.other_fragment)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try                 setPopUpTo(findNavController().backQueue.first().destination.id, true)

Comment: backQueue is a private api.

Answer (score -6):

You can do as simple as:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

If you want to check the count you can do as:

```
getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()
```