# Navigate to fragment on FAB click (Navigation Architecture Components)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, kotlin

I have no idea how to, using the new navigation architecture component, navigate from my main screen (with a `FloatingActionButton` attatched to a `BottomAppBar`) to another screen **without** the app bar.

When I click the fab I want my next screen (fragment?) to slide in from the right.  The problem is where do I put my `BottomAppBar`?  If I put it in my `MainActivity` then I have the issue of the `FloatingActionButton` not having a `NavController` set.  I also cannot put my `BottomAppBar` in my Fragment.  I am at a loss.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ran into this issue today and I found out that there is a simple and elegant solution for it.

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)

fabAdd.setOnClickListener {
   navController.navigate(R.id.yourFragment)
}
```

This takes care of the navigation. Then you must control the visibility of your `BottomAppBar` inside your `Activity`.

Comment: You don't need the line `Navigation.setViewNavController(fabAdd, navController)` - that would only be necessary if you want to use `fabAdd.findNavController()` (and, since you already have a reference to your `NavController`, that isn't something you'd ever need to do).

Comment: How knows better about this great API but the creator of it! Thank you ianhanniballake for the great library and your comment. I will take that line out.

Comment: What is R.id.navHostFragment?

Comment: <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_sample"
            app:defaultNavHost="true" />

Comment: This results in `Type mismatch. Required: Fragment Found: Int`

Comment: Okay I found soulution that doesn't destory BottomAppBar. Check out my answer

Comment: @DariushMalek it gives error; "Activity does not have a NavController set on". I don't understand I'm using FragmentContainerView

Answer (score 6):

You could have your `BottomAppBar` in `MainActivity` and access your `FloatingActionButton` in your fragment as follows

```
activity?.fab?.setOnClickListener { 
    /*...*/
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment, mDataBundle)
}
```

You could hide the `BottomAppBar` from another activity as follows

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Make sure you `.show()` the `BottomAppBar` while returning to previous fragment

Answer (score 1):

Put it in MainActivity and setOnClickListener in `onStart()` of the activity and it will work fine.

```
override fun onStart() {
  super.onStart()
  floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
    it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.yourFragment)
   }
}
```

*Note:This solution is like and hack and better is to follow Activity LifeCycle and setUp OnClickListener when the activity is ready to interact.*

[Similar question [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53902696/7972699)

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to navigate to certain fragment (not the star one) in the beginning for some reason, and also you have to graphs for one activity, here is what I suggest:
this method will start activity

```
companion object {

        const val REQUEST_OR_CONFIRM = "request_or_confirm"
        const val IS_JUST_VIEW = "IS_JUST_VIEW"
        const val MODEL = "model"

        fun open(activity: Activity, isRequestOrConfirm: Boolean, isJustView: Boolean = false, model: DataModel? = null) {
            val intent = Intent(activity, HostActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(REQUEST_OR_CONFIRM, isRequestOrConfirm)
            intent.putExtra(IS_JUST_VIEW, isJustView)
            intent.putExtra(MODEL, model)
            activity.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

and then in, onCreate method of Host Activity, first decide which graph to use and then pass the intent extras bundle so the start fragment can decide what to do:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase_nav)
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(REQUEST_OR_CONFIRM, true)) {
            findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).setGraph(R.navigation.nav_first_scenario, intent.extras)
        } else {
            findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).setGraph(R.navigation.nav_second_scenario, intent.extras)
        }
    }
```

and here's how you can decide what to do in start fragment:

```
if (arguments != null && arguments!!.getBoolean(HostActivity.IS_JUST_VIEW)){
    navigateToYourDestinationFrag(arguments!!.getParcelable<DataModel>(HostActivity.MODEL))
}
```

and then navigate like you would do normally:

```
private fun navigateToYourDestinationFrag(model: DataModel) {
        val action = StartFragmentDirections.actionStartFragmentToOtherFragment(model)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

here's how your graph might look in case you wanted to jump to the third fragment in the beginning
[image]

PS: make sure you will handle back button on the third fragment, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043428/handling-back-button-in-android-navigation-component/56150209#56150209)'s a solution

**UPDATE**:
as EpicPandaForce mentioned, you can also start activities using Navigation Components:
to do that, first add the Activity to your existing graph, either by the + icon (which didn't work for me) or by manually adding in the xml:

```
 <activity
        android:id="@+id/secondActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_second"
        android:name="com.amin.SecondActivity" >
    </activity>
```

you can also add arguments and use them just like you would in a fragment, with navArgs()

```
 <activity
        android:id="@+id/secondActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_second"
        android:name="com.amin.SecondActivity" >
        <argument
            android:name="testArgument"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="helloWorld" />
    </activity>
```

in koltin,here's how you would use the argument, First declare args with the type of generated class named after you activity, in this case SecondActivityArgs in top of your activity class:

```
val args: SecondActivityArgsby by navArgs()
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
print(args.testArgument)
```

Comment: I thought you don't have to manually start Activities anymore because you can use `ActivityDestination`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't destroy BottomAppBar. Add this to MainActivity only and don't do anything else

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment

fabAdd.setOnClickListener {
   findNavController(navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.fab)
}
```