# Navigation Component: Cannot find NavController

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

I am using Navigation Component for navigating in my app. It works fine inside fragments but it fails to find the nav host in the activity that holds the actual navigation host.

I am trying to open a new fragment when the user clicks on FAB, which I included in Main activity's XML. When I call findNavController() it fails to find the controller. The nav host controller is in the XML layout. I can't understand why it fails to find it.

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnActivityComponentRequest {
    override fun getTabLayout(): TabLayout {
        return this.tabLayout
    }

    override fun getFap(): FloatingActionButton {
        return this.floatingActionButton
    }

    private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
    private lateinit var floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        this.tabLayout = tabs
        this.floatingActionButton = fab

        fab.setOnClickListener {

         it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.addNewWorkoutFragment)

        }
    }
}
```

Activity main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".domain.MainActivity"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:text="Test 1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:text="Test 2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="right|top"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bar"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: `I can't understand why it fails to find it.` does it return `null`?

Comment: Yes, it returns null. I managed to find a solution. I will put it as an answer so it is more readable

Comment: `Navigation.findNavController(
        this,
        R.id.nav_host)
.navigate(R.id.addNewWorkoutFragment)`  Try Using this it should work

Comment: I have tried that too but it didn't work. I have posted my solution.

Comment: can you try setting up OnClickListener in `onStart()` of activity and check.
your solution's seem's like a hack.

Comment: You are correct, setting onClickListener in onStart() worked :) Thank you

Comment: i will post it as an answer.Do accept.

Comment: Sure, I will accept :)

Comment: ***Check the solution in Link.*** [How to get NavController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75574270/7370837)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try setting up onClickListener of Fab button in `onStart` of the Activity as in `onCreate` Activity is just inflating the View and haven't set the `NavHostController`. So if you setup  `onClickListener` in onStart of activity is will work as expected.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    this.tabLayout = tabs
    this.floatingActionButton = fab
  }

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
      it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.addNewWorkoutFragment)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Now SOF has thank's feature next to answer u can use that. :P anyway's ur WC @KhamidjonKhamidov

Comment: yeah in onCreate() it's crashed but in onStart() it's working properly.

Comment: Weirdly, I had the same problem with a new `Bottom Navigation Activity` project. Moving the nav controller logic into `onStart()` like so fixed the issue!

Answer (score 26):

I was getting the same exeception until I managed to get the navController this way:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment_container_view_id) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Obtained from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502269/illegalstateexception-link-does-not-have-a-navcontroller-set):

Before finding the nav controller, you need to set the view, if you are using binding:

```
binding = BaseLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
val view = binding.root
setContentView(view)
```

If not:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Use the corresponding binding for fragments.

Comment: This is actually what is stated in navigation component documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate

"When creating the NavHostFragment using FragmentContainerView or if manually adding the NavHostFragment to your activity via a FragmentTransaction, attempting to retrieve the NavController in onCreate() of an Activity via Navigation.findNavController(Activity, @IdRes int) will fail. You should retrieve the NavController directly from the NavHostFragment instead."

Comment: `Before finding the nav controller, you need to set the view` this is what helped me.

Answer (score 18):

In Java you can find `NavController` inside activity this way:

```java
Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host).navigate(R.id.YourFragment);
```

Answer (score 4):

Retrieve it later, in onPostCreate. like this:

```
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_container_view);        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be that FAB was added to the activity or a fragment different from the one used by NavHost fragment. In this case, when you call `it.findNavController()` it cannot find the navigation controller.

You can either check that your FAB belongs to the fragment pulled by NavHost or call an Activity's `findNavController(<id>)` and pass it id of the fragment you're looking up

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                .navigate(R.id.addNewWorkoutFragment)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Kotlin Only**

[Android Navigation KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx?gclid=Cj0KCQiA47GNBhDrARIsAKfZ2rBOZo25IuM4SMmkgZ0nYfmKnRFTr1pR9VAqzlE__wxEpC1XSfI-2vEaAi9iEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#navigation) provides an extension function for `Activity`

All I had to do was

```
findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment).navigate(R.id.to_someFragment)
```

I do have the following dependencies in my `app/gradle.build.kts` file (

```
implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5")
implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5")
implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5")
```

---

**Using Directions**

Alternatively you could also use generated *Directions* class.  Since this is a global action the *Directions* class is found in the `NavigationDirections.to_someFragment()`

```
//very useful if you're passing args then you could do something like
//NavigationDirections.to_someFragment(myArg)    
NavigationDirections.to_someFragment()findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment).navigate(NavigationDirections.to_someFragment())
```

---

Side-note the specific extension function is being contributed from the `runtime-ktx` aar

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that activity that holds navigation controller... doesn't have navigation component.

The solution is to manually set the NavController to each view contained in the activity.

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
Navigation.setViewNavController(fab, navController)
```

Now this would work:

```
fab.setOnClickListener {

    it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.addNewWorkoutFragment)

}
```

I still don't understand why this works the way it works so any explanation would be more than welcome :)

As of now, Android API simply doesn't make much sense.

Source: [Navigate to fragment on FAB click (Navigation Architecture Components)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085222/navigate-to-fragment-on-fab-click-navigation-architecture-components)

Answer (score 1):

you can still get access in your oncreate by doing

```
    //the id would be the id of the Fragment Element In Your Activity XML File
    val navGraph = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.activity_main)
    binding.mainFab.setOnClickListener {
        navGraph.navigate(R.id.destinationFragment)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer helpful. In your activity paste this code

```
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.yourDestination)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **Extension** version for Kotlin:

```
 fun AppCompatActivity.findNavController(
    @IdRes navHostViewId: Int
): NavController {
    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(navHostViewId) as NavHostFragment

    return navHostFragment.navController
}
```

The `navHostViewId` is id of your `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `binding.root.findNavController().navigate(id)`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access navController in OnCreate of Activity is to access it after inflating the layout
that can achieved by kotlin extention function `doOnPreDraw()`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val navController: NavController
        get() = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.root.doOnPreDraw {
            // here you can safely use navController
            binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController)
        }
    }
}
```