# How to use findNavController() in Activity

Tags: android

I want to change fragment by using navigation component but I want to change fragment from activity. How can I change fragment from activity?

```
tab_layout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabReselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

            override fun onTabSelected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                if (tab_layout.selectedTabPosition == **Summary_Fragment().findNavController().navigate(R.id.sum_to_report)**
                }
            }
        })
```

i expect the output to change fragment in ID `sum_to_report`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NavController` is used to navigate from one destination to another destination which can be retrieved by following one of the static methods :

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(Fragment)
Navigation.findNavController(Activity, @IdRes int viewId)
Navigation.findNavController(View)
```

After retrieving a `NavController`, use the `navigate()` method to navigate to the destination. The `navigate()` method which accepts Resource Id. The ID can be the ID of a specific destination in the navigation graph or of an action. Using the ID of the action, instead of the resource ID of the destination.
For example,

```
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_navigationFragment_to_blankFragment)
```

Comment: I guess, the question is how to get that View/ViewId

Comment: I believe the ViewId is the id of the FragmentContainerView widget.

Answer (score 1):

Using **NavHostFragment** reference issue can be resolved.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.mvvmkotlin
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import com.example.mvvmkotlin.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp()|| super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```