# how to make custom back button to go back to certain destination using navigation controller in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I need to make a custom behaviour, when the user press the back button then the user will go to certain destination programatically. I actually have read this [Handling back button in Android Navigation Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043428/handling-back-button-in-android-navigation-component)

but I don't understand how to use that custom back button code.it seems weird to me.

I have tried using this code below

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_setting, container, false)

        // set custom back button
        val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {

            // navigate to certain destination
            Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).popBackStack(R.id.destination_create_event, false)


        }


        return fragmentView
    }
```

but I get type mismatch error like this
[image]

Comment: The same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create new Instance of the OnBackPressedCallback abstract class and implement its abstract method .

I hope this helps you:

```
        val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true){
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                        Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).popBackStack(R.id.destination_create_event, false)
        }


    })

    // The callback can be enabled or disabled here or in the lambda

}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. The OPs code is fine; I think it's using the wrong imports.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini As you can see in the screenshot ,  a type mismatch error eccurs and the error message says an OnBackPressedCallback required but found boolean

Comment: @ahooee i've tried your solution, but I have error like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/imLjY.png

Comment: @Alexa289 Just add the  closing addCallback function parenthesis before 'return fragmentView' statement .see the screenshot: [ScreenShot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MGKQ9Ns8VCVZ4zQoYkDnsmph9Sn3Wmkb/view)