# Android Navigation Component ActionBar Up/Parent event handling

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment, android-navigation

So I'm using Android Navigation in my app, and I'm running into this case:

I have 2 fragments A -> B, now whenever the user navigate back from B -> A, I want to show an alert before the back event.

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54522734/6793787) answer, and got this solution:

```
// code on fragment B's onViewCreated()
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    alert("Are you sure to quit?")
}
```

And this solution work well when I press the hardware back button, but when I press the back button on the Toolbar, the callback doesn't get called. Please help me, thank you.

[image]

Here my MainActivity's Navigation setup:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Comment: That's the Up button, not the back button. Those are different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fragment B in `onCreateView` enable options menu

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

And override `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) { // ActionBar back/parent button is pressed
        // onBackPressed() // to return back to Fragment A
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add code as below -

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    alert("Are you sure to quit?")
    return false
}
```