# Home icon press in Navigation component bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have integrated `Navigation component` in my app. I'm using it along with `Bottom Navigation`.

I have 3 tabs [`Home`, `Notification`, `Account`]. Switching the navigation is working perfectly fine.

Problem for me lies here.
 
From `Home`  fragment the app navigates to many other fragments  `Home` -> `FragA` -> `FragB` -> `FragC`. But when i click on the `Home` icon in bottom navigation, I want to clear all the Fragments and come to the initial state. 
Currently Im coming to the home screen, but when i click back all previous fragments `FragA` -> `FragB` -> `FragC` are showing up.

How can this be achieved?

Not attaching any code as it's irrelevant

Comment: have you try inclusive in pop behavior?

Comment: Yes. But no luck

Comment: this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974492/2849550) is similar to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your fragments from fragmentManager:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(FragA).commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(FragB).commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(FragC).commit();
```

and then attach it again to fragmentManager.
if you want to save the stats of fragments use detach() instead of remove.
more details is available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Comment: I'm not making use of supportFragmentManager

Comment: how do you load fragments without fragmentManager?

Comment: I'm using navigation component