# How to (proper) open Activity/Fragment from Foreground Service using Navigation Components

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

In my use case, I have a Foreground Service bounded to a `Notification`.

The user can kill the app but the Foreground Service is still alive. Additionally, the user can click in the `Notification` and open the `HomeFragment`.

My current `NavGraph` looks like this:

[image]

Currently, I am using the `NavDeepLinkBuilder` to open my `HomeFragment` when the user clicks in the Notification:

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
    .setDestination(R.id.homeFragment)
    .createPendingIntent()

return NotificationCompat.Builder()
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .build()
```

This code works, but I am facing a few problems:

- On `onBackPressed`, the `HomeFragment` is "blinking" and I need to press the back button twice to actually close the app from the `HomeFragment`.
- This approach doesn't look right since I have no deep links in my app;
- The `NavDeepLinkBuilder` [does not accept any `Action` (where I define the `popUpTo`, `popUpToInclusive` etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974492/1945754)), only the destinationId

Due to this scenario, my question is: the `NavDeepLinkBuilder` is the proper way to open my `HomeFragment` from the Service?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution of this?  I having the same issue.

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException sorry for the late reply. No issues were caused using this approach, so I kept exact same way that I described in the question and it is working well

Comment: what context are you using inside the service? As they said you must use the activity context.

Comment: @HimanshuMalik using application context and didn't face a single error so far...