# backstack does not clear while navigating from fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

Here is my code

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/fragment1"
  android:name="com.example.app.Fragment1"
  android:label="SignatureFragment"
  tools:layout="@layout/layout_fragment1">
    <action
      android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_main_activity"
      app:destination="@id/main_activity"
      app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_from_right"
      app:exitAnim="@anim/no_anim"
      app:launchSingleTop="true"
      app:popEnterAnim="@anim/no_anim"
      app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_to_right"
      app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_graph_id"
      app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</fragment>

<activity
  android:id="@+id/main_activity"
  android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
  android:label="MainActivity"
  tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" />
```

Now the code for navigation

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_main_activity)
```

When I navigate to activity and press back, the `fragment` is still there. I want to clear the backstack after opening the activity.

I tried to remove the animation and also tried with removing `app:launchSingleTop`, but no success.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by navigating to activity; here there is a single activity and only navigation occurs in the level of fragments .. isn't you mean the home fragment of the `NavHostFragment`?

Comment: @Zain, actually I have few fragments before fragments, but they are removed from the backstack if I use `app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_graph_id"` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`

Comment: did you already check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514758/how-to-clear-navigation-stack-after-navigating-to-another-fragment-in-android

Comment: @G.Ciardini: yes I checked that answer and already following the `app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_graph_id"` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** 
Jetpack Navigation is intended to work with single activity and does not fully support activity navigation with parameters passed to `action`s

Thus to clear stack when navigating from one activity to another you will still need to call `activity.finish()`

**Edit end**

The thing is `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_main_activity)` wont work.

Try to navigate via `navigate(@NonNull NavDirections directions)`. In your case it will look something like this

```
findNavController().navigate(
     Fragment1Directions.actionFragment1ToMainActivity())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this but the same result. The fragment was there when I go back.

Comment: Hm weird. Are you sure you have you called 'finish()' inside an initial activity after navigating?

Comment: do you mean the `finish()` while setting the graph from the very first activity here? `navController.setGraph(graph, extras)` it just closes the activity

Comment: Nope. I mean `finish()` after you call your method that navigates you to the other activity. Right after `findNavController().navigate(
     Fragment1Directions.actionFragment1ToMainActivity())`. It will do the thing. I've already added this explanation to the answer