# Android navigation component - unregister LiveData after navigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I am using [Android Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) to navigate between fragment screens.

After navigating to a new fragment screen, I want to unregister all the `LiveData` observations that I registered using the fragment life cycle. The problem is that the fragment is not getting detached until the navigation is complete and I am getting unintended events from `LiveData`.

How to handle this?

I tried using [app:popUpTo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974492/1129332) but that happens too late.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What does "until the navigation is complete" mean? Your Fragment is stopped immediately (the next frame) after you call `navigate()`. LiveData does not send events to stopped fragments.

Comment: Can you upload a sample code in which you call `observe`?
The beauty in `LiveData` is that you don’t need to worry about observations since it’s automatically bound the the lifecycle of the fragment. I want to see which lifecycle owner you send to `observe` function

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel I use `this` that resolves to Fragment.

Comment: I believe you need to use `viewLifecycleOwner` (or something similar, I'm writing from memory) instead `this`. Please try and update.