# Remove navigation back button after user logout

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I'm using Android Jetpack Navigation Component for my app. It has Two screen (Fragment) which are `homeFragment` and `loginFragment`. The `homeFragment` is the start destination. After logout from `homeFragment` to `loginFragment`, the navigation back button shows up, it will back to `homeFragment` again when click, that's not correct. I expect the back button not shown in `loginFragment`, and if user press system back app exit. The `nav_graph.xml` is setting properly as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974492/2361959) was told:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="cn.helptool.qxscales.LoginFragment"
        android:label="Login" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="cn.helptool.qxscales.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

[image: Login screen with navigate back button]

Answer (score 1):

After read [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration)

[image: AppBarConfiguration]

**Add both of `loginFragment` and `homeFragment` as top level destinations, the problem fixed.**

```kotlin
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.loginFragment, R.id.homeFragment).build()
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```