# Popping back to "home" using multiple back stacks

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I have a project that's using multiple back stacks via Jetpack Navigation `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0-beta02`. I'm investigating a way to navigate back home from another navigation graph. For simplicity, let's assume my main navigation graph contains two root destinations that get configured as bottom navigation destinations.

`graph_main`:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/graph_main"
    app:startDestination="@+id/graph_home">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/graph_home"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/graph_settings"/>

</navigation>
```

`graph_home` contains a start destination and a details screen:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/graph_home"
    app:startDestination="@+id/home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:name="com.example.playground.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_to_details"
            app:destination="@id/details"/>

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:name="com.example.playground.ui.home.DetailsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_details"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_details"/>

</navigation>
```

`graph_settings` just contains a start destination with some action(?) to navigate back to the start destination of `graph_home`:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/graph_settings"
    app:startDestination="@+id/settings">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:name="com.example.playground.ui.settings.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings">

        <!-- maybe? -->
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settings_to_home"
            app:destination="@id/graph_home"/>

    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

1. User launches the app to the `home` destination in `graph_home`.
2. User taps a list item, and system navigates to the `details` destination in `graph_home`.
3. User taps the "Settings" bottom navigation tab, and system navigates to the `settings` destination in `graph_settings`.
4. User taps a button on the `settings` screen that causes the system to pop all back stacks back to the `home` screen.

How can I set this up so that in step #4, the original home screen `Fragment` is shown (not a copy of it) and the back stacks are empty after navigating back home (tapping the system back button closes the app)?

Comment: What about `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive`? 
 I hope it works for you.  https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop

Comment: See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974492/11835023

Comment: @tancolo that solution appears to work in the sense that it navigates back to the root list screen of the home graph. However, if I tap the "Home" bottom nav item after navigating, the previous home nav stack is presented with the details screen on top. So the home nav stack doesn't appear to get cleared for some reason.