# Fragment getting initialised before Android 12 Splash screen ends

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-splashscreen

I have a FragmentContainerView in my MainActivity which uses a nav graph.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav" />
```

I want my fragments to wait till I get some data from an API before I hide my splash screen. I am using android 12 [Splash Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen). This is how I am trying to accomplishing it(from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#suspend-drawing)):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    installSplashScreen()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //Set up an OnPreDrawListener to the root view.
    val content: View = findViewById(android.R.id.content)
    content.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(
        object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
            override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                // Check if the initial data is ready.
                return if (mainActivityViewModel.isDataReady()) {
                    // The content is ready; start drawing.
                    Timber.tag("Splash").d("data ready")
                    content.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                    true
                    } else {
                        Timber.tag("Splash").d("data not ready")
    
                        // The content is not ready; suspend.
                        false
                        }
                    }
                }
        )
```

The Splash screen is going away only after I get the data. But the issue is that my Fragments callbacks like `onViewCreated` gets invoked even before my data is ready. This is causing issues because I rely on data that I fetch during splash screen to do some tasks.

How can I make sure, my fragments won't get initialised before my Splash screen goes away??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Splash screen is going away only after I get the data. But the issue is that my Fragments callbacks like onViewCreated gets invoked even before my data is ready.

[Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) and [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) lifecycle callbacks are only triggered by the system on the appropriate times. They can't be triggered by developers; there is no control on that. So, you can't stop `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated`,.. from taking place. i.e. you can't stop activity/fragment from initialization; otherwise you could have ANRs.

**More in detail**

Initializations of activities/fragments shouldn't be seized until some background task finishes; this literally will cause ANRs.

While you're seizing the drawing of the activity's root layout using `addOnPreDrawListener`; this doesn't mean that the activity's initialization (i.e. `onCreate()`) get seized, because both are working asynchronously, and the `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, &  `onResume()` will get return normally.

The same is true for fragment's callbacks where the fragment's initialization (i.e. `onCreateView()`, `onViewCreated`...) is coupled with the activity's `onCreate()`.

Now, as the initialization  of the start destination fragment relies on the API data; then this particular fragment shouldn't be the start destination.

So, to fix this you need to create a some splash screen fragment as the start destination that doesn't rely on the API data.

Depending on the API incoming data, you can decide a navigation to the original fragment through the `navController`:

```
return if (mainActivityViewModel.isDataReady()) {
    
    // Do the transaction to the original fragment through the navController
    
    // The content is ready; start drawing.
    Timber.tag("Splash").d("data ready")
    content.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
    true
    
    } else {
    
        // Not transaction is needed, keep the splash screen fragment
    
        Timber.tag("Splash").d("data not ready")

        // The content is not ready; suspend.
        false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sense. But how can I make sure, i wont come back to this "SplashFragment" when I click back??

Comment: @hushed_voice You can clear it from the back stack by setting `app:popUpTo='your_nav_graph_id' and app:popUpToInclusive="true"` like [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974492/9851608)

Comment: Another alternative If you don't want to create a new fragment; then the original fragment should not update its content unless it's triggered by some `LiveData` through a Shared ViewModel; or you can use a listener for that.