# Jetpack conditional navigation

Tags: android-layout, android-navigation, android-jetpack

I want to change my start navigation fragment based on a condition. My start fragment could be fragment one or two. Is there a way to implement it?

[image]

Comment: Currently, there is no support right of the library to determine condition. You should do it within the custom NavFragment which determines the `startDestination`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out this question and its solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929290/is-it-possible-to-set-startdestination-conditionally-using-android-navigation-ar#) // Also added Java code here

Just converted Kotlin code to Java

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.home_nav_fragment);  // Hostfragment
NavInflater inflater = navHostFragment.getNavController().getNavInflater();
NavGraph graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_main);
graph.setDefaultArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
graph.setStartDestination(R.id.fragment1);

navHostFragment.getNavController().setGraph(graph);
navHostFragment.getNavController().getGraph().setDefaultArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navHostFragment.getNavController());
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this question and it's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929290/is-it-possible-to-set-startdestination-conditionally-using-android-navigation-ar#)

I have also added a comment below the answer to clear it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks.. Do you have an example of this implementation using Java?

Comment: No, I don't, but I guess it shouldn't be difficult to rewrite that code in Java.