# Android Navigation Component: Start at a different destination than home, programmatically?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to implement a multiple `navigation controller` with multiple back stack `BottomNavigationView`, as per the [github examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample). However, the example uses a different nav graph for each tab, which makes things easy. In my case I need to use the same nav graph for all of my tabs, but with different start destinations, than the "home destination" set in the nav graph.

So far I've managed to modify the `NavigationExtensions` file in order to achieve the single navgraph for all tabs, and I get multiple `navControllers` with their own back stacks, but I cannot figure out how to start a nav graph at a different destination.

I've tried using `.navigate` when getting the navcontroller, but since it's not yet attached, it does not work. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 61):

We had a requirement wherein the displayed start screen would depend if the user has logged on, what we did was the following:

1. Remove app:startDestination on the navigation `XML` if it exists
2. On your main activity's XML, remove the following fields inside the `<fragment>` tag:  `app:defaultNavHost="true"` and `app:navGraph`
3. On our main Activity's `onCreate()`, we create a `NavGraph` object :

   ```
   NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.your_nav_hostfragment);    
   NavGraph navGraph = navController.getNavInflater().inflate(R.navigation.your_navigation_xml);
   ```
4. Then  depending on your requirement, you can set the start destination on the NavGraph using setStartDestination, then apply the NavGraph to the NavController:

   ```
       if (condition) {
           navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.screen1);
       } else {
           navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.screen2);
       }
       navController.setGraph(navGraph);
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much, this brought me one step closer to solving my problem. Is there a way to pass arguments to the fragment passed as the start destination? I have a fragment that loads different data when different ids are passed.

Comment: You can try the Safe Args plugin of the Navigation Component, see this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args

Comment: I am already using safe args, but the directions create an action, that should be passed to a NavController with `.navigate(action)`, which cannot be passed as a startDestination to the navGraph. Any diead?

Comment: In that case, then I am not aware of any Navigation Component-related solution to your requirement. Instead of feeding the data as Fragment arguments, I think it might be better that your Fragments fetch the needed data from somewhere else (like a Repository class).

Comment: Thanks @akubi. My Fragments actually do that, I only feed them a string ID so the fragment knows what to draw from the underlying DB/repository/cache.

Comment: @AhsanSaeed I had the same problem. Leaving `app:defaultNavHost="true"` in `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` fixes it. Android reference [says](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started): "The `app:defaultNavHost="true"` attribute ensures that your `NavHostFragment` intercepts the system Back button. Note that only one `NavHost` can be the default. If you have multiple hosts in the same layout (two-pane layouts, for example), be sure to specify only one default `NavHost`."

Comment: In my case, when I override the navGraph within the host activity, the fragment that is the start destination was giving error and crashing the app where I use requireContext() reporting; "Fragment is not attached to any context". This answer solved my issue, a big  thanks to him/her. This is really weird in the official documentation there is not any description or note that states this issue. @akubi where did you gather this information from?

Comment: However, in my case it still worked even though I kept using `app:startDestination` and `app:defaultNavHost="true"`. I think the main issue for my case was setting navGraph both from within xml resource and runtime.

Comment: @Kozmotronik when I wrote the answer my intention was to set the nav graph start destination in code rather than use XML

Comment: If I don't remove app:defaultNavHost="true" then it works like a charm. If i removed defaultNavHost then back navigation not worked properly.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote two extensions to do the job. First is to be used to change destination in the current node. The second is to be used to traverse multiple times into nested graphs

```
_main_graph
 |
 |_nested_graph_1
   |
   |_nested_graph_2  
     |
     |_nested_graph_3
       |
       |_nested_graph_4
         |
         |_change this destination!!!!
```

```
fun NavController.changeNodeDestination(nodeId: Int, destinationId: Int): NavController {
    val graph = graph.findNode(nodeId) as NavGraph
    graph.startDestination = destinationId
    return this
}

fun NavController.changeNodeDestination(vararg nodeIds: Int, destinationId: Int): NavController {
    var currentNode = graph

    nodeIds.forEachIndexed { index, i ->
        currentNode = currentNode.findNode(nodeIds[index]) as NavGraph
    }
    currentNode.startDestination = destinationId
    return this
}
```

Usage:

```
        findNavController().changeNodeDestination(
            R.id.navigation_login,
            R.id.nav_change_password,                  // GO two levels inside nested graphs
            destinationId = startDestination
        ).navigate(navID, bundle)
```