# Dynamically change startDestination of nested navigation graph inside of a BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to update my app to use `BottomNavigationView`. The first tab contains a `HostFragment` with a loading spinner that performs a network request to determine which fragment, either `HomeFragment` or `LockedFragment`, should be shown in that tab.

`MainActivity` handles the initial setup of the `BottomNavigationView`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(
            R.id.nav_host_container
        ) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.mainFragment)
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
```

My main nav graph looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@+id/home">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/home"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/list"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/form"/>
</navigation>
```

with the home graph looking like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    app:startDestination="@+id/hostFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/hostFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.bottomnav.homescreen.HostFragment"
        android:label="Host">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_hostFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_hostFragment_to_lockedFragment"
            app:destination="@id/lockedFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.bottomnav.homescreen.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/lockedFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.bottomnav.homescreen.LockedFragment"
        android:label="Locked"/>
</navigation>
```

`HostFragment` get's shown fine and loads it's data:

```
class HostFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_host, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        determineFragmentToShow()
    }

    private fun determineFragmentToShow() {
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            // mock network call to determine tab
            delay(1500)

            // show HomeFragment for the sake of the example, but note that
            // this would be dependent on the network call's result above
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_hostFragment_to_homeFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

which successfully navigates us to `HomeFragment`.

Now the problem is that whenever I press the back button from `HomeFragment` it goes back to `HostFragment` instead of closing the app.[You can see the behavior in this video here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gXzBvP0z5X86OmSvWdEfLH6wV3Q_frmT/view?usp=sharing)

I tried to set the `popUpTo` and `popUpInclusive` tags inside of `home.xml` like this:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/hostFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.bottomnav.homescreen.HostFragment"
        android:label="Host">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_hostFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/home"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_hostFragment_to_lockedFragment"
            app:destination="@id/lockedFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/home"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
```

That got the app to close when pressing back from `HomeFragment`, but now each time I switch to a new tab, it creates a new instance of the fragment and adds it to the backstack. Pressing the back button then will traverse them all backwards. [You can see that behavior in this video here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gc-NseIiwvluvru1ovqVsFxr_a4sWWUK/view?usp=sharing)

***So how can I update the start destination of a nested navigation graph?***

I'm using the latest `2.4.0-alpha10` of navigation component so that I can get native support for multiple backstacks. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to utilize the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62968347/6042392) to get a solution working for me.

Inside of `determineFragmentToShow()` in `HostFragment`, I just replaced `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_hostFragment_to_homeFragment)` with

```
val navController = findNavController()
val graph = navController.graph
val walletGraph = graph.findNode(R.id.home) as NavGraph
walletGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.homeFragment)
navController.navigate(R.id.action_hostFragment_to_homeFragment)
```

I still needed to include the `popUpTo` and `popUpInclusive` tags here

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/hostFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.bottomnav.homescreen.HostFragment"
        android:label="Host">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_hostFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/home"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_hostFragment_to_lockedFragment"
            app:destination="@id/lockedFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/home"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
```

but this got me the back behavior I was looking for!