# Is it possible to have dynamic destination in Nested Navigation Graph Android?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack

I have implemented a nested graph in Navigation graph, which is having 2 graphs. In the first graph, there are 3 fragments and in the second graph, there are 2 fragments. Graph 2 is included in graph 1. I want to navigate to (graph 1 step 1) to (graph 2 step 2). We can not define action between two nested fragments. So is there any way by which we can assign the dynamic destination to navigation?

[image]

> Graph 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
        android:name="com.navigationgraphexample.fragments.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="fragment_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_dashboardFragment_to_stepOneFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/stepOneFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_dashboardFragment_to_sub_nav"
            app:destination="@id/sub_nav" />

    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/stepOneFragment"
        android:name="com.navigationgraphexample.fragments.StepOneFragment"
        android:label="fragment_step_one"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_step_one">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_stepOneFragment_to_stepTwoFragment"
            app:destination="@id/stepTwoFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/stepTwoFragment"
        android:name="com.navigationgraphexample.fragments.StepTwoFragment"
        android:label="fragment_step_two"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_step_two" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/notificationFragment"
        android:name="com.navigationgraphexample.fragments.NotificationFragment"
        android:label="fragment_notification"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notification" >
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:uri="myapp.com/{myargs}"
            />
        <argument android:name="myargs"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="1" />
    </fragment>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/sub_nav" />
</navigation>
```

> Graph 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sub_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/createNewTaskFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:name="com.navigationgraphexample.fragments.ListFragment"
        android:label="fragment_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/createNewTaskFragment"
        android:name="com.navigationgraphexample.fragments.CreateNewTaskFragment"
        android:label="fragment_create_new_task"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_create_new_task" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_createNewTaskFragment_to_listFragment"
            app:destination="@id/listFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173002/how-to-change-start-destination-of-a-navigation-graph-programmatically-jet-pac) solution but it is not for the nested graph!

Comment: You can try manually building a NavHostFragment and Graph objects manually, but keep in mind you can't access the controller in onCreate.

Answer (score 17):

As far as `class NavGraph extends NavDestination`, you can try the following to change nested graph's `startDestination` before calling `navigate` to `sub_nav`:

```
val graph = navController.graph.findNode(R.id.sub_nav)
if (graph is NavGraph) {
    graph.startDestination = R.id.createNewTaskFragment
}
```

**UPD**: Since version 2.4.0 all Navigation artifacts have been rewritten in Kotlin, so the setter should be accessed by it's original name:

```
graph.setStartDestination(R.id.createNewTaskFragment)
```

Comment: can use this to find the current destination nested graph: findNavController().currentDestination?.parent?.findNode(R.id.nestedGraph)