# How to create a start destination of navigation graph programmatically in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have a host (activity) which contains 5 fragments and one of the fragment also acts like a host (nested graph) contains 2 fragments. I want to create a start destination dynamically in this host fragment.

I created the start destination dynamically in activity but can't create in fragment as it can't refer the id of nav host.

In activity I did this:

```
    val navHostFragment = nav_host_fragment as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    val navInflater = navController.navInflater
    val graph = navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_main)
    graph.startDestination = R.id.detail_fragment
    val navShipmentId = NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(shipmentId).build()
    navHostFragment.navController.graph = graph
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change start destination of a navigation graph programmatically \[Jetpack\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173002/how-to-change-start-destination-of-a-navigation-graph-programmatically-jetpack)

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this issue