# How can I remove startDestination attribute from navigation_main?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

**navigation_main file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_main_countries_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_main_countries_fragment"
        android:name="com.test.app.fragments.CountriesFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_countries" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_main_categories_fragment"
        android:name="com.test.app.fragments.CategoriesFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_categories" />

</navigation>
```

Is it possible to remove `app:startDestination="@id/navigation_main_countries_fragment"` from `navigation_main` file and do it programmatically? If the `int x` was 0 then run  `countries_fragment` otherwise `categories_fragment`.

I'm using Java language.

Please test your answer before posting it because many people posted their answers but unfortunately the answers do not work.

Comment: This question totally duplicates your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062281/how-can-i-add-startdestination-programmatically-accoridng-the-value). The only difference I see is that you actually asking for Java solutions. You should've edit that question and add this detail, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Also why you keep adding [android-jetpack-compose] tag? [Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) is a completely different kotlin-only technology, it doesn't seems like your question has anything to do with this tag.

Answer (score 1):

The navigation documentation explains it pretty well [on Conditional Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional) using navigation components.

Comment: But the question still is it possible to delay startDestination or not, Because if it is not supported then I'll use your solution. I still trying since the morning

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to remove app:startDestination="@id/navigation_main_countries_fragment" from navigation_main file

No.

> and do it programmatically?

Yes. but you should override it.

You must define a dummy destination in the xmL and then change it in your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/empty_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/empty_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.EmptyFragment"
        android:label="EmptyFragment" />
</navigation>
```

```
val targetDestination = if (x == 0)
    R.id.navigation_main_countries_fragment
else
    R.id.navigation_main_categories_fragment

val navController = ....
navController.graph = navController.graph.apply { startDestination = targetDestination }
```