# How to remove back button from background fragment when dialog is popped in NavigationComponent?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-navigation

I am using latest Navigation Component and have some `DialogFragment`. I use `dialog` element to specify my `DialogFragment`s in my navigation graph. But when dialog is popped, back fragment showing back button which I want to remove.

[image]

How can I not show back button in background fragment when dialog is popped?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50301820/remove-up-button-from-action-bar-when-navigating-using-bottomnavigationview-with

Comment: Can you [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828)? This should be something Navigation does for you automatically.

Comment: @ianhanniballake that means so far there is no such option to remove it?

Comment: @musooff - [using AppBarConfiguration](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration) as suggested in the first comment with every dialog you can trigger from a top level destination would certainly be a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has been added with `2.1.0-alpha06` release referring to this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134089818)